# Best way to build a camera app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, camera

I am thinking of building a camera application - with the ability to do image processing (adjust contrast, apply different image filters) while you are taking picture or after the pictures has taken.

The app will also have the ability of drag and drop icons.

At the end you are able to export the edited images either to the camera roll or app memory.

There is already many apps out there like this. (Line Camera) etc...

Just wondering what is the best way to build such app.
Can I build the app purely with Objective C ios sdk? or do i need to build it with C++/cocos2d, etc...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why would you use Cocos2D? Either way you will be using the Objective-C programming language.

Comment: When you clicked on the "Ask Question" button, there was a help text to the right: "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.". I think you should ask a less generic and more specific question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very broad, so here is a broad answer...

#### Accessing the camera/photo library

First you'll need to access the camera using `UIImagePickerController` to either take a new photo or grab one from your photo library.  You can read up on how to accomplish this here: [Camera Programming Topics for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

#### Image Manipulation

AviarySDK has much of this already built for you.  Very easy to set up and use in your apps.  You can download their sample app for free in the app store if you want to see what it can do.  Check it out here: http://aviary.com/

Alternatively, read up on Core Image if you'd like to avoid third-party libraries.  See [Core Image Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html) for more information.

Comment: In short, I am building AviarySDK - with in app purchases. Thanks for the info, I will take a look into the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need for cocos2d which is a game engine.
You can accomplish everything you mentioned using only Objective-C.

If you want real-time effects you will need to dive into OpenGL. you can use [GLKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKit_Collection/Introduction/Introduction.html) if you target iOS 5 and above.

Comment: "using only Objective-C" should be "using only the default frameworks on iOS". I doubt the libobjc library in itself would be enough...

Comment: @H2CO3 i was referring to the programming language rather than the library